# How to make a an async connection to couchbase server from Flask (Quart) app?

Tags: python, asynchronous, couchbase, python-asyncio, quart

I am trying to convert a Flask app to a Quart app to add async module and gain some performance as discussed in this [article](https://hackernoon.com/3x-faster-than-flask-8e89bfbe8e4f). For this, I am connecting to a Couchbase bucket using the acouchbase.Bucket object. The problem is quart is slower and it crashes during the load test.  Here is the code I am trying:

```
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, jsonify, g
from quart_openapi import Pint, Resource
import couchbase.experimental
couchbase.experimental.enable()
from acouchbase.bucket import Bucket

app = Pint(__name__, title = 'SomeTitle')

async def get_db():
    """
    Helper function to initialize and retrive the Bucket object if not 
    already present.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'cb_bucket'):
        g.cb_bucket = Bucket('couchbase://localhost/bucketname', 'username', 'password')
        await g.cb_bucket.connect()
    return g.cb_bucket

@app.route("/apiname/<string:xId>")
class apiname(Resource):
    async def get(self, xId):  
        cb = await get_db()
        pickle_in = open('mlmodel', 'rb')
        model = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        y_pred_proba = model.predict_proba(Member).tolist()
    return jsonify(y_pred_proba)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
app.run(port = 5000, debug = True)
```

App compiles without a problem though during the load test it performs bad and crashes after a while. A very similar flask app (with out any async module) is faster than the quart app but you would expect quart with async module to be faster than the flask app:

Flask equivalent looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify  
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
# Coucbase connections
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost/')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket('bucketname')

app = Flask(__name__) 
api = Api(app=app)

@api.route("/apiname/<string:xId>")
class apiname(Resource):
    def get(self, xId):
        Member = cb.get(xId)
        pickle_in = open('mlmodel', 'rb')
        model = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        y_pred_proba = model.predict_proba(Member).tolist()
    return jsonify(y_pred_proba)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(port = 5000, debug = True)
```

Here is a comparison of quart app vs flask app. Flask looks like 10 times faster than the Quart app, which stops after the test with this error _ 96930 segmentation fault_.

Quart: [image: Quart APP]
Flask: [image: Flask]

Any answer/recommendation appreciated.

Comment: Wondering which benchmarking/testing tool is being used?

Comment: Posted pictures are from wrk. We also tested it with gatling.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're mixing [Bucket](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/rest-api/rest-bucket-intro.html) with [Cluster](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/rest-api/rest-cluster-intro.html).

From the [CouchBase documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html#connecting):

> To connect to a Couchbase bucket, you must use Couchbase Role-Based
>   Access Control (RBAC). This is fully described in the section
>   Authorization. An authenticator, containing username and password,
>   should be defined, and then passed to the cluster. Following
>   successful authentication, the bucket can be opened.

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
bucket = cluster.open_bucket('bucket-name')
```

So, for your case, it should be something like:

```
if not hasattr(g, 'cb_bucket'):
  cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
  authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
  cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
  bucket = await cluster.open_bucket('bucket-name')
return bucket
```

Comment: [According to this CouchBase documentation:](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/async-programming.html)  you need to use _acoucbase.Bucket_ object which directly connects to a bucket.